# how to use scikit learn PCA function

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing an ARCHIVED course on ML on edx and thus i am not getting answers to my queries there - hence i am posting here.

the exercise i am working on is dimension reduction. we are required to create a function do_PCA on the ARMADILLO data. the function is also given:

```
def do_PCA:
  pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='full')
  pca.fit(armadillo)
  PCA(copy=True, n_components=2, whiten=False)
  T = pca.transform(armadillo)
  armadillo.shape
  T.shape
  ##print(T) ## i added this extra line
  return None
```

My question is: Does T represent the reduced dataset or 'armadillo'? and dont we have to change the 'return None' to 'return T' or 'return armadillo' in order to later plot the reduced dataset?

hope my question makes sense!!!

### once i know the answer to this, i have a subsequent question as well!!

ok.. the above part was answered by @vivekkumar....now the second part

in the same lab assignment, the instructor makes us run the following code:

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(5000): pca = do_PCA(armadillo)
time_delta = datetime.datetime.now() - t1
```

the variable time_delta is then used in scatter plot.

My question is as follows:

why is he running the do_PCA 5000x??

the instructor has a note which reads: "PCA is ran 5000x in order to help decrease the potential of rogue processes altering the speed of execution."

thanks again

Comment: What do you observe about `T`, when printing the shape. Do you find the second element of `shape()` same as `armadillo` or equal to 2?

Comment: Yes. You have to return T.

Comment: @VivekKumar the T is a 2-column matrix. and thanks.....tried it and it works!

Comment: Yes. T is 2-column matrix, means that the original has been transformed into 2 columns by pca (n_components=2)

Comment: @VivekKumar thannks ... please do look at my follow up question

Comment: Without more description, its very hard to say why he used it 5000 times. Also is the code correctly formatted. I mean is the time_delta out of the for_loop?

Comment: Also, how is he using the scatter plot with time_delta values?

Comment: @VivekKumar the time_delta is used to print the time it took to run pca 5000x.. i dont know how to paste an image here from my jupyter notebook otherwise i wd have pasted the plot

Comment: So there are 5000 points in the scatter plot? That means the time_delta is inside the for loop.

Comment: @VivekKumar here is the code which plots:

Comment: if not pca is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_title('PCA, build time: ' + str(time_delta))
        ax.scatter(pca[:,0], pca[:,1], c='blue', marker='.', alpha=0.75)

Comment: No, in this scatter plot, time_delta is only used for setting the title,nothing else. So only thing that is understandable to do PCA 5000 times is to reinitialize the internal parameters of PCA again and again randomly.